# Kill process by ParentProcessID

Tags: powershell, wmi, wmic

I want to kill a running process by its ParentProcessID. I want to do it like you can do it in the commandline:

```
wmic process where parentprocessid= 3008 terminate
```

But now the thing is, in PowerShell I've the ParentProcessID as a variable like this:

```
$p = 3008
```

And now I would like to kill the process by the varibale `$p` but this doesn't work:

```
wmic process where parentprocessid= $p terminate
```

How can I kill a process by its ParentProcessID, if I have the ParentProcessID stored in a variable?

Comment: Hi, why you do not use `Get-Process`? You should absolutely use wmic?

Comment: `wmic process where parentprocessid=$p terminate`

Comment: @kekimian - `Get-Process` does not give you information on the parent process

Comment: @Matt Tag edits will allow you to change just one character in the title/body in the same edit :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I know. I don't like making little snip edits when there is something else to do. Also don't care to fight with the OP on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, it was just to remove the space between the "=" and the variable name.

```
wmic process where parentprocessid=$p terminate
```

Answer (score 3):

Retrieve the Win32_Process object with `Get-WmiObject` and pipe it to `Invoke-WmiMethod` to invoke the `Terminate` method:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "ParentProcessId=$p" | Invoke-WmiMethod Terminate
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$parentId = 3008
$name = "Process name"

Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Process | 
where {$_.ParentProcessId -eq $parentId -and $_.Name -eq $name} | 
foreach {$_.terminate(0)}
```

Added `$name` parameter cause there may be several child processes. If you need to kill'em all just skip `-and $_.Name -eq $name`