# Sending a Ctrl+C (SIGINT) to a powershell process

Tags: powershell, sigint, taskkill

I am trying to send a Ctrl+C signal to a powershell process on windows. I tried Taskkill, Kill commands in Windows but it is not working. I also tried to use TaskManager but it is not doing the expected. Also tried the " SendSignal" app mentioned on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/813086/can-i-send-a-ctrl-c-sigint-to-an-application-on-windows), but that app is not actually sending the signal, the process is still running after executing it.

Can someone please help.

Thanks,

Comment: Show what you wrote, in PowerShell, when using `taskkill`, please.  You're asking how to properly kill a process, it seems... but you've gone down a path (sending `Ctrl+C`) which isn't going to work efficiently or easily for you in any way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kill process by ParentProcessID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33891243/kill-process-by-parentprocessid)

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> seems to do the trick, though I sometimes have to do it a few times to get the SIGINT to take.